# DDEV Router Unhealthy State in TYPO3 Setup: Health Check Timed Out

Tags: docker, typo3, traefik, health-check, ddev

I am setting up a ***TYPO3*** project using ***DDEV***.
I've successfully configured the project and started all the containers, except for **ddev-router**, which is stuck in an **unhealthy state**.
I've tried debugging the issue using various Docker commands but haven't been able to resolve it.

---

## Steps to Reproduce:

1. Initialized DDEV configuration with the following command:

   `ddev config --project-type=typo3 --docroot=public --create-docroot --php-version 8.1`
2. Started DDEV with:

   `ddev start`
3. Installed an additional proxy fix:

   `ddev get ddev/ddev-proxy-support`

## Expected Behavior

All containers, including **ddev-router**, should start and be in a healthy state.

---

## Debugging steps:

- **Docker Logs**:
  Ran `docker logs ddev-router` to check for error messages.

  *Expectation*: To find error messages that could point to the root cause.

  *Result*: Only found warning messages related to TLS options, which are unlikely to be the cause.
- **Docker Inspect**: Used `docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" ddev-router` to check the health status.

  *Expectation*: To get detailed information on why the health check is failing.

  *Result*: The output indicated an "unhealthy" status but did not provide further details.
- **Source Code Review**: Checked the health check script [traefik_healthcheck.sh](https://github.com/ddev/ddev/blob/master/containers/ddev-traefik-router/traefik_healthcheck.sh) to understand what it does.

  *Expectation*: To identify the command or condition causing the health check to fail.

  *Result*: Found that the script uses a `curl` command to check health, which is exiting with status 22.
- **Docker Exec**: Entered the ddev-router container using `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` and ran *ps aux | grep traefik* to check if Traefik is running.

  *Expectation*: To confirm that Traefik is running as it should be.

  *Result*: Traefik is running, as evidenced by the process list.
- **Environment Variable**: Checked for the existence of the `TRAEFIK_MONITOR_PORT` environment variable within the `ddev-router` container.

  *Expectation*: To find the port number used for monitoring Traefik's health.

  *Result*: The environment variable is not defined.
- **Open Ports**: Checked all open ports within the `ddev-router` container using `netstat -tuln`.

  *Expectation*: To check which ports are open and listening.

  *Result*: [output of netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QQFn.png)

Comment: You've done a great job reporting on this, but unfortunately it's still missing too much information and this is a very poor venue to debug it. Please come over to Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k or the DDEV issue queue, https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues and provide the full output of `ddev debug test` as a file. You didn't even mention what OS or Docker provider you're using here, etc.